# Does a function between sets induce a homomorphism between the respective permutation groups?

Tags: permutations, group-actions

Let $X,Y$ be finite sets, and let $\Sigma(X),\Sigma(Y)$ be their respective permutation groups. Consider a function $f:X\to Y$.

> Is there a homomorphism $\phi:\Sigma(X)\to\Sigma(Y)$ induced somehow by $f$?

If $f$ is injective (basically an inclusion), then $\Sigma(X)$ will be isomorphic to a subgroup of $\Sigma(Y)$.
But if $f$ is not injective, I guess there are some conditions to verify, right? How does it work?

A reference would also be very welcome.

Comment: If $X=\{1,2,3\}$, and $Y=\{4,5\}$, and $f(1)=f(2)=4$, and $f(3)=5$, then what is $\phi(1\ 3\ 2)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, exactly. Are there some conditions to avoid this case (other than injectivity)?

Comment: I suppose if $Y$ has only one element then you're OK.